# Not able to customize the radio button in Jquery mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I have a fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/coderslay/ZYKxc/2/

In this i need to place the details button at the right. But i am not able to place it at the right. How to do it?

Comment: As an variant you can modify jquery css file or create your own and there set styles for `ui-btn`

Comment: I Tried doing something like what you said http://jsfiddle.net/coderslay/ZYKxc/5/ But didn't succeed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to brute force the styling you could separate the two elements and float them.

```
<label for="radio-choice-1">
    <div style="float: left; margin-top: 10px;">Cat</div>
    <div style="float: right;">
        <a href="index.html" data-role="button" class="ui-btn-right" data-inline="true">Details</a>
    </div>
</label>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/d3NuT/